# Exclude .min.js from wildcard %.js in makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, wildcard, gnu

I have a build target in my makefile that is used to compress .js files but it's trying to re-compress .min.js files. I'd like to exclude those .min.js files from my $(wildcard) file list but I'm blanking on how to do this.

Ideas?

Currently have this set, which returns .min.js obviously.

```
CSS_MIN := $(patsubst %.css, %.min.css, $(wildcard $(CSS)/*.css))
JS_MIN := $(patsubst %.js, %.min.js, $(wildcard $(JS)/*.js))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$(filter-out)` function ([Text Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions)):

> $(filter pattern…,text)

```
Returns all whitespace-separated words in text that do match any of the pattern words, removing any words that do not match. The patterns are written using ‘%’, just like the patterns used in the patsubst function above.
```

> $(filter-out pattern…,text)
>
> Returns all whitespace-separated words in text that do not match any of the pattern words, removing the words that do match one or more. This is the exact opposite of the filter function.
>
> For example, given:
>
> ```
> objects=main1.o foo.o main2.o bar.o
> mains=main1.o main2.o
> ```
>
> the following generates a list which contains all the object files not in ‘mains’:
>
> ```
> $(filter-out $(mains),$(objects))
> ```

So use

```
JS_MIN := $(patsubst %.js, %.min.js, $(filter-out %.min.js,$(wildcard $(JS)/*.js)))
```

or

```
JS_MIN := $(filter-out %.min.min.js,$(patsubst %.js, %.min.js, $(wildcard $(JS)/*.js)))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I had messed this up by having $(wildcard) in both the 1st and 2nd parameter in filter-out with *.min.js and *.js

Comment: Having indicated that you tried `filter-out` in your question would have made for a better question and shown more "research effort".